# Reduce count of each value from list by some value Python

Tags: python, list

I wandering, is there a way to reduce number of each value in list by reducing its count by some number (1,2,3..10...) or to set count divided by some number.
For example:

```
list = ["one","one","three","three","four","three","four", "four"]
```

Result in first case (reduce number by each value of 2):

```
["three", "four"]
```

Result in second case (divide by 2 --> this is tricky because 3/2 is 1.5, but for example to round the number to 1 ):

```
["one", "three", "four"]
```

Comment: why wasn't `"one"` covered by condition *reduce number by each value of 2*?

Comment: Well `one` appears two times in `list`. In first case count of `one` is 2 and I reduce count of each value, so now, count is 0, or there is no `one` in list .
In second case, I divide value by 2, so 2/2 is 1, so i have `one` in the result list that appears one time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain, repeat

l = ["one","one","three","three","four","three","four", "four"]

n = 2
c = Counter(l).items()
list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(k, v-n) for k,v in c))
# ['three', 'four']
```

---

For the second case we can take the floor division by `n=2`:

```
list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(k, v//n) for k,v in c))
# ['one', 'three', 'four']
```